# Doctrine 2 and OAuth2.0 Server PHP Client Credentials are invalid

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, oauth-2.0, credentials, entitymanager

I am trying to implement **OAuth2** with **Doctrine** as an entity manager. I followed this tutorial exactly:

http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/doctrine2/

Here is my code that is called when a user makes a request to the API:

```
// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

$clientStorage  = $entityManager->getRepository('OAuthClient');
$clients = $clientStorage->findAll();
print_r($clients); // We are getting the clients from the database.
$userStorage = $entityManager->getRepository('OAuthUser');
$accessTokenStorage  = $entityManager->getRepository('OAuthAccessToken');
$authorizationCodeStorage = $entityManager->getRepository('OAuthAuthorizationCode');
$refreshTokenStorage = $entityManager->getRepository('OAuthRefreshToken');

//Pass the doctrine storage objects to the OAuth2 server class
$server = new \OAuth2\Server([
    'client_credentials' => $clientStorage,
    'user_credentials'   => $userStorage,
    'access_token'       => $accessTokenStorage,
    'authorization_code' => $authorizationCodeStorage,
    'refresh_token'      => $refreshTokenStorage,
], [
    'auth_code_lifetime' => 30,
    'refresh_token_lifetime' => 30,
]);

$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($clientStorage));

// handle the request
$server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

Whenever a call using the correct credentials is made, I get this response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => OAuthClient Object
        (
            [id:OAuthClient:private] => 1
            [client_identifier:OAuthClient:private] => testclient
            [client_secret:OAuthClient:private] => testpass
            [redirect_uri:OAuthClient:private] => http://fake.com
            [hashOptions:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cost] => 11
                )

        )

    [1] => OAuthClient Object
        (
            [id:OAuthClient:private] => 2
            [client_identifier:OAuthClient:private] => trevor
            [client_secret:OAuthClient:private] => hutto
            [redirect_uri:OAuthClient:private] => https://www.another.com
            [hashOptions:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cost] => 11
                )

        )

)
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}
```

So we are getting the clients from the database, we should be checking them, and returning that they in fact exists and issuing an access token. However, for some reason, OAuth2 Server (can be seen [here](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php)) can not match the given credentials with the stored credentials.

I do not think this is a Doctrine problem because I can retrieve the results fairly easily using findAll().

> My question is:
>
> Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In the tutorial (http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/doctrine2/) they fail to mention that when the client secret is checked with against a hashed version of the provided client secret.

In the tutorial they do not hash the example client secret when they put it in the database.

If you hash your client secret when inserting it into the database, it will work as expected.